# Whites of Their Eyes

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #1: Restricted Title: xkcd 1xxx](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7352/)</sub>

---

Encoding where F equals seventy

_____ Tenkula, a heavy metal musician

Vadodara financial services company & bank

Tall brother in Super Mario

Tomohiro _____, a Japanese professional wrestler

Comment: We want more puzzles from you, SeptaCube, cool and simple like this one.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First we solve the clues noticing that

> they are all 5 letters long and there are a lot of I's in them
>  `ASCII  Encoding where F equals seventy`
>  `MIIKA  _____ Tenkula, a heavy metal musician`
>  `ICICI  Vadodara financial services company & bank`
>  `LUIGI  Tall brother in Super Mario`
>  `ISHII  Tomohiro _____, a Japanese professional wrestler`

Then we

> according to the title, color the I's white
>  [image]

Then

> interpreting each 5-letter word as a 5-digit binary number with white I's as 1's and others as 0's, we get the numbers `3 12 21 5 19`

Using

> A1Z26 we get the word **CLUES**

We look at the

> clues. Each is five words. Some words have I's and some don't.

Taking

> the words with I's as 1's and the ones without as 0's we again get 5 5-digit binary numbers: `16 1 12 5 18`

Again using

> A1Z26 we get the word: **PALER** which aptly describes the *whites of their eyes*

Comment: Good work so far, but you don't have the answer yet!

Comment: @SeptaCube even cooler! Eye think eye got it now ;)

Comment: @op This is amazing! So many subpuzzles in such a short text! Kudos for you!